# nginx different routes for / and /*

Tags: nginx

I'd like to route `/` to `a.sock` and `/(.*)` to `b.sock`.

I tried

```
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/a.sock;
        proxy_read_timeout 30;
        proxy_connect_timeout 30;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    }
    location ~ /(.*) {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/b.sock;
        proxy_read_timeout 30;
        proxy_connect_timeout 30;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    }
```

with different ordering too.

Can this be achived with nginx, if so, how?

My take is, according to the documentation anything ending with a `/` assumes a wildcard after the `/` and the plain route without the regex takes precedence.

Essentially the backend on `b.sock` has a route definition of `/:term` or `/{term}` depending on which routing lib you use, but has no handler for `/`.
You're probably thinking "so add a handler for `/` and call it a day". I might do that, but it's a workaround. I would like `a.sock` to handle `/`.

So again, can this be done with nginx and how?

Comment: Your regular expression `/(.*)` also matches `/`.

Comment: Have you tried replacing "location /" by "location ~ ^/$" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use exact matching for homepage, e.g. `location = / { … }`. The `location / { … }` will apply for the rest of the pages.

The exact matching (with equals sign) has priority over prefix location (no equals sign).

Comment: IIRC, the order is `=` where `nginx` stops processing immediately, then regex, lastly a match. I think the original config in the question is always matching on regex.